# list view item selected scroll automatically to top?

Tags: android, listview

```
    </ListView>` 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:paddingTop="51dp"
    android:divider="#00ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#006300ff"
    android:background="@drawable/sfando"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">`

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            adapterView.requestFocusFromTouch();
             adapterView.setSelection(i);

           itemnum = view;
            return false;
        }
    });
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color. @Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    itemnum.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}


        listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```

this is my java code and i don't understand whi scrolls automatically?
thanks, excuse for my poor experience, but i'm new

......................................

Comment: i don't understand why?

Comment: is your list view refreshing on select? what is your list item click listener code like?

Comment: Please fix your code ;)

Comment: thanks, i've edited my java code

Comment: i have found solution. Thanks anymore